# Porting app from LWUIT to CodenameOne

Tags: lwuit, porting, codenameone

I have 3 apps developed in LWUIT using the Resource editor and adding more functionallity with Netbeans. I want to port them to codenameone. What is the best way to do that?

I see that the navite `Components`from LWUIT have an equivalent `Component`in codenameone, but J2ME methods and classes , now have to be ported to J2SE, is that right? 
The methods in the `StateMachineBase` have changed too. `showForm()` for example, doesn't exist now.What further changes are in StateMachineBase?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by creating a new Codename One project then just copy your source code/resource files and fix the import statements.

You can't use the MIDP API's anymore (and you can't use J2SE either), there are new [API's](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html) and a new lifecycle object which you can use for pretty much everything. `showForm` does exist and wasn't modified, I'm not exactly sure why you didn't find it.

Generally [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is much simpler since it doesn't have the project hierarchy issue and you don't need to deal with MIDP/RIM/Android differences. Its all handled for you.